# How to display item of nested json array in component using Angular 7

Tags: json, angular, angular7

How can I display "empName" and other details of this JSON in my table component in loop?

I'm using a third party API which provides a nested JSON object in return when I send employerID to the API URL.

After subscribing I'm storing the response in a var "AllPostedJobs"

```
{
    "status": "All Jobs",
    "result": [
        {
            "_id": "5c90fd3cfc7f3b0017803319",
            "job_title": "Web Designer",
            "job_desc": "test description ...",
            "location": "Mangalore",
            "experiance": "Freshers",
            "job_type": "Full-Time",
            "salary_package": "3L",
            "job_keywords": "Photoshop, Illustrator",
            "email_id": "hr@shreemithra.com",
            "employerID": "5c7e99c2a7a9eb00174de2b2",
            "company_name": "Shreemithra Designs",
            "AppliedStudentDetails": [
                {
                    "_id": "5c9393c1a918d60017de7e55",
                    "empName": "Anup",
                    "empID": "5c939375a918d60017de7e53",
                    "job_title": "Web Designer"
                }
            ],
            "__v": 1
        },
        {
            "_id": "5c913570cb78a100177ab23a",
            "job_title": "Full Stack Developer",
            "job_desc": "htjhsv dhsd jh jds fjshgdfkhsdmhfd;lw eiwiwemsd. This is a sample job description.",
            "location": "Pune",
            "experiance": "2 Years",
            "job_type": "Part-Time",
            "salary_package": "8L - 10L PA",
            "job_keywords": "Angular, Node JS, React, HTML5. CSS3",
            "email_id": "info@shreemithra.com",
            "employerID": "5c7e99c2a7a9eb00174de2b2",
            "company_name": "Shreemithra Designs",
            "AppliedStudentDetails": [
                {
                    "_id": "5c9393c9a918d60017de7e56",
                    "empName": "Anup",
                    "empID": "5c939375a918d60017de7e53",
                    "job_title": "Full Stack Developer"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5ca60fa5ba17730017182ca8",
                    "empName": "Amit Pateriya",
                    "empID": "5c7795acfd39640017ca4c37",
                    "job_title": "Full Stack Developer"
                }
            ],
            "__v": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you stuck? Please show us what you have attempted and what the problem is.

Comment: Find below the screenshot. URL: [link](http://imgur.com/a/YWLAurV)

Am displaying all posted jobs in my component using loop. Now I want to display the applicants of each job posted in an another component on click of the button.

Answer (score 0):

*You can bind display data by binding controls in an HTML template to properties of your  component.*

The easiest way to display a component property is to bind the property name through interpolation. With interpolation, you put the property name in the view template, enclosed in double curly braces:`{{AllPostedJobs.status}}`.

```
<div  id="result-container" *ngFor="let record of AllPostedJobs.result">
   <another-component [record]= "record"></another-component>
</div>
```

Or depending on your need you can hand over entire result data to another-component.

Now your another-component, should have `@Input` defined to handle the incoming data:

```
export class AnotherComponent {
    @Input() record: Array<any>;
```

In your another-component template:

```
<div *ngFor="let student of record?.AppliedStudentDetails">
      <span>{{student.empName}}</span>
      <span [innerText]="student.job_title"></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Actually, am storing "result" in my variable "AllPostedJobs". But I understood and am able to display the details. But my problem is the empName other details should display in another component with the click of the button in the parent component where it displays the jobs. Find below the screenshot. URL: https://imgur.com/a/YWLAurV

Comment: @PareshMithra, in that case you should be using a `@Input` in your child component and pass the rest of data to it.. updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> The simplest way is when you receive data  from api then send it to a
>   function then apply multiples loop alter your data by add keys in
>   front of data and that values for example

```
var data = [{"id":1, "name":"smith","applicant":{"roll": 32,"class":10}}];
data[0].applicantRoll = data[0].applicant.roll;
data[0].applicantClass = data[0].applicant.class;
```

now you can apply *ngfor easily, try this.

Comment: my problem is the empName and other details should display in another component with the click of the button in the parent component where it displays the jobs. Find below the screenshot. URL: imgur.com/a/YWLAurV

Comment: Okay, so why you not use eventemitter?